# Getting deadlock for insert and select statement(sql server 2014) in java application

Tags: java, tomcat7, deadlock, sql-server-2014-express

In my application there are many threads which uses insert and select statement to store/retrieve data from database 
So, i am getting deadlock on PRD environment, i have observe deadlock from application log file

```
Unable to read Cycle (ID: 1-A | PosID: 1 due to SQL Exception : 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 129) was deadlocked on lock | 
communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4762)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1682)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:955)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207)
    at com.ilume.db.adapter.module.RoutingModul.getRoutes(RoutingModul.java:2867)
    at com.ilume.db.adapter.module.RoutingModul.getAccounts(RoutingModul.java:2826)
    at com.ilume.db.adapter.module.RoutingModul.getAccounts(RoutingModul.java:2651)
    at com.ilume.db.adapter.module.RoutingModul.getEmployee(RoutingModul.java:2141)
    at com.ilume.db.adapter.module.RoutingModul.getEmployee(RoutingModul.java:1925)
    at com.ilume.db.adapter.module.RoutingModul.getCycle(RoutingModul.java:767)
    at com.ilume.jti.logic.controller.tingController.readCycle(RoutingController.java:225)
    at com.ilume.jti.logic.controller.tingController.<init>(RoutingController.java:137)
    at com.ilume.jti.logic.controller.ukraine.tingController.<init>(tingController.java:30)
    at com.ilume.jti.logic.controller.ukraine.eThread.run(UkraineThread.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and i am not able to reproduce same situation on my development environment.
Please give me suggestion to resolve this kind of deadlock and how to get more clear understanding to capture deadlock.

Thank you

Comment: Don't use images to show text data. Copy the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Format your question properly when asking.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question based on the information you've provided. Maybe your transaction isolation isn't correct, maybe you've written deadlock-prone code, who knows?